# Can you add a model to the Marionette.Application object?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am a newbie to backbone and marionette. I have a User Model which contains if the user is logged in, their name, id, info, etc... Is it possible to create a new instance of the UserModel inside the new Marionette.Application call?

Something like:

```
var app = new Marionette.Application({ model: new UserModel() });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an endpoint on your server-side API that returns the currently logged-in user (/me is sometimes used in this effect).

Client side, create a subclass or your `User` model with `/me` as the URL, and fetch it on app start.

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var CurrentUser = User.extend({
    url: '/me'
});

MyApp.addInitializer(function(){
    this.currentUser = new CurrentUser();
    this.currentUser.fetch();
});
```

You could also shortcut this with :

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({});

MyApp.addInitializer(function(){
    this.currentUser = new User({url:'/me'});
    this.currentUser.fetch();
});
```